# Interaction of variables in regression

Tags: regression, interaction

I have two variables that predict fraud behavior (dependent variable). The independent variables are perception of fraud being wrong (1-5) and probability of being caught (1-5). The dependent variable is frequency of committing fraud in the last 5 years (never, once, 2-3 times, 4 times and more). 
Two questions:

1. What kind of regression should I use? Ordinal?
2. Theory predicts that interaction of these two variables predicts the fraud. For those who perceive it wrong, the probability of being caught affects differently than for those who perceive it right. How should I enter this to the model?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 1. Ordinal logistic is the first tool that springs to mind. If you have a good sense of the distribution of the people who committed fraud 4 + times per year, then other options may be available, but ordinal logistic looks good.

1. The usual way to enter an interaction is by multiplying the two variables. Whether that is appropriate here depends on what 1-5 mean. If these are anchored by proportions (e.g 1 = 0%, 2 = 20% or whatever) then multiplying may be possible. If you treat them as categorical you will have a lot of terms.  How big is your data set?

Comment: 1000 samples. and about 1-5: in the question "how likely to be caught in case of fraud" the answers are "not very likely, not likely, likely and very likely" (actually it is 1-4).

Comment: Then I think you have to treat them as categorical. Most software will create the interaction for you. (e.g. SAS, R, etc)